Creating a dymamic array which sums different columns depending on row
I would like to sum up columns but the columns to be summed up would be different in each row depending on a a cell in that row
e.g. in row 1, I want to sum up columns 1,2,3,4 but in row 2 I want to sum up 5,6,7,8,9,10,11 and 12
I have been provided the previous answer that works with a range
=BYROW(A2:M3,LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(α,,1),--TEXTSPLIT(TAKE(α,,1),",")))))

, but not an array:
=BYROW(FILTER($a$2:$m$3,$n$2:$n$5="yes"),LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(α,,1),--TEXTSPLIT(TAKE(α,,1),","))))) 

it seems to be taking the first referenced column in each case i.e. first and 5th respectively

Hey, for FILTER > A Boolean array whose height or width is the same as the array.  Please check it.

Assuming that N5 is a typo, TAKE or CHOOSECOLS are 'acting out'. Not sure why. You can use INDEX instead: =BYROW(FILTER(A2:M3,N2:N3="yes"),LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(α,,1),--TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(α,1),","))))). @Mayukh Bhattacharya Do you have any clue?

@VBasic2008, TAKE seems to be the culprit.

Try using the following formula:


    =TOCOL(BYROW(A2:N4,LAMBDA(α, 
 SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(DROP(α,,-1),TAKE(α,,-1)="Yes"),
 --TEXTSPLIT(TAKE(α,,1),",")+1)))),2)


You don't need an INDEX() or TAKE() to make your formula work, here is quick fix: Solution proposed based on my earlier solution to the OP.
• Using SINGLE() --> @
    =BYROW(FILTER(A2:M4,N2:N4="Yes"),LAMBDA(α,
 SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(α,,1),--TEXTSPLIT(@α,",")))))


The reason why the SINGLE() or @ would work, is when using the FILTER() array within BYROW() the latter will check each row, and  takes up the top-left value from the array using SINGLE() or @ which is usually called as Implicit Intersection Operator and you can read more on its usages in range or cell or an array here.

The above goes same with TAKE() as well, which will certainly work if @ is added before TAKE(), however it is not needed when used within BYROW()
=BYROW(FILTER(A2:M4,N2:N4="Yes"),LAMBDA(α,
 SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(α,,1),--TEXTSPLIT(@TAKE(α,,1),",")))))


Refers to same in the above context:

SINGLE(α)
@α
INDEX(α,1)
@TAKE(α,,1)
@INDEX(α,,1)


As suggested in comments below by JvdV Sir:


=BYROW(FILTER(A2:M4,N2:N4="Yes"),LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(α,TEXTSPLIT(@α,",")+1))))


Or,
=BYROW(FILTER(A2:M4,N2:N4="Yes"),LAMBDA(α,SUM(INDEX(α,TEXTSPLIT(@α,",")+1))))



LAMBDA() part can also be written like: LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(α,TEXTSPLIT(@α,",")+1)) to save a function. However, I like to use INDEX() here too over CHOOSECOLS(). I'm just used to that I guess...

@JvdV Sir, yes that works. =BYROW(FILTER(A2:M4,N2:N4="Yes"),LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(α,TEXTSPLIT(@α,",")+1)))) Thank you very much for you advise!!!


TAKE was the cause of your (and mine - have seen it many times, so I tend to use INDEX) problem (could be a bug in Excel).
=LAMBDA(data, criteria,
    LET(
        filtered, FILTER(data, criteria),
        BYROW(
            filtered,
            LAMBDA(row_,
                SUM(
                    CHOOSECOLS(
                        DROP(row_, , 1),
                        --TEXTSPLIT(
                            INDEX(row_, 1, 1),
                            ","
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)(A2:M4, N2:N4 = "yes")


But how do you explain that CHOOSECOLS also doesn't work? Also, look at Mayukh's solution that has that same TAKE but works.

@VBasic2008 Sir, what you used is basically called SINGLE() or @ --> Implicit Intersection Operator and hence why it is working! When you are using the same within BYROW() it checks for each row, and takes up the top-left value, while when using INDEX(α,,1) or TAKE(α,,1) it wont work, as it will only split and give the first split vals and not all of it!

@VBasic2008, TAKE + TEXTSPLIT seems to act in unexpected way when not used with a range. Try for example: =LET(arr, {"1,2","3,4"}, a_range, F15:G15, VSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(TAKE(a_range, 1, 1), ","), TEXTSPLIT(TAKE(arr, 1, 1), ","), TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(arr, 1, 1), ","))) where F15:G15 has 1,2 3,4
